# pandas read_csv does not capture final (unnamed) column into dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a csv file in the following format

```
myHeader
myJunk
myDate
A, B, C, D
, b, c, d
dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD, EXTRA_INFO_STRING
dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD, EXTRA_INFO_STRING
dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD, EXTRA_INFO_STRING
```

When I create my data frame using

```
dlogframe = pd.read_csv(myPath, header=3)
```

I get the following error (my data is more complex than above example, but functionally identical)

```
pandas._parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 393 fields in line 9, saw 394
```

How can I give the EXTRA_INFO column a name and have those strings included in my dataframe?

**[EDIT]**

I figured out how to skip the troublesome row, but now the data is not aligned properly

```
from StringIO import StringIO
s = """myHeader
myJunk
myDate
A, B, C, D
, b, c, d
dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD, EXTRA_INFO_STRING
dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD, EXTRA_INFO_STRING
dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD, EXTRA_INFO_STRING"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=3, skiprows=[4])
>>print df

            A       B       C                   D
dataA   dataB   dataC   dataD   EXTRA_INFO_STRING
dataA   dataB   dataC   dataD   EXTRA_INFO_STRING
dataA   dataB   dataC   dataD   EXTRA_INFO_STRING
```

What I want is:

```
A       B       C       D       MY_INFO
dataA   dataB   dataC   dataD   EXTRA_INFO_STRING
dataA   dataB   dataC   dataD   EXTRA_INFO_STRING
dataA   dataB   dataC   dataD   EXTRA_INFO_STRING
```

Answer (score 0):

If only row after header is missing `EXTRA_INFO_STRING`, you can load column names and data separately:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=None, skiprows=5)
```

Following code (may be not a very elegant one) will load column names:

```
df.columns = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=None, 
                       nrows=1, skiprows=3).T.append(['MY_INFO'])[0]
# 0      A       B       C       D             MY_INFO
# 0  dataA   dataB   dataC   dataD   EXTRA_INFO_STRING
# 1  dataA   dataB   dataC   dataD   EXTRA_INFO_STRING
# 2  dataA   dataB   dataC   dataD   EXTRA_INFO_STRING
```

Data used in test:

```
s = """myHeader
myJunk
myDate
A, B, C, D
, b, c, d
dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD, EXTRA_INFO_STRING
dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD, EXTRA_INFO_STRING
dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD, EXTRA_INFO_STRING"""
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my data to include a row below the column headers that I left out, sorry for the oversight. Now the error gets thrown

Comment: @BrianLeach does your update mean that some of your fields do NOT include extra info?

Comment: even if there is no info string, there is still a comma at the end of the data. I just added an additional reply with more info, the data is still slightly offset

Comment: @BrianLeach I mean that `, b, c, d` row has 4 columns (no extra `,` at the end), that's why 5th column with 5 columns is treated as erroneous

Comment: I tried to get the data to ignore that funny row (skiprows=[4]), although now the data is not aligned quite properly

Comment: @BrianLeach in that case, you can do it in two passes, for example. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), skiprows=5, header = None, index_col = False)
df.columns = list("ABCDE")
```

Sometimes if you have problem with read_csv numeric conversions you could add dtype=object
into read_csv call and deal with conversions later on your own using DataFrame.astype.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I tried that seems to get data in the format that you want. Basic idea is 'ignore all problematic rows' (that's possible if you know about the file structure).

```
x = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(s), names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'more_info'], header=None, skiprows=5)
```

This gives output in the format you desire.

My experience has been with `read_csv`, one has to try a few combinations before one gets what one wants.

Hope this helps.